Por qué aparece el botón en una posición que no es la que yo he puesto?
He creado un proyecto, he añadido una barra y un botón encima de la barra.
Al ejecutar el proyecto, aparece el botón en la posición 0,0 y no donde yo lo he puesto.
¿Esto a que puede ser debido?

El código del layout es el siguiente:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="406dp"
        android:layout_height="121dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="2dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="2dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SuperIRC"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="30dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="37dp" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="339dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="37dp" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


código ? falta eso para ver que estas haciendo

Agrega tu layout .xml, recuerda aportar mas información,

Revisa mi respuesta, los atributos que usas solo mostrarían los cambios en la previsa,.voy a modificar el layout para que pruebes en tu app

Es muy importante que sepas que los atributos que usas para posicionar los elementos en tu ConstraintLayout:
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX 

y
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY

No existen en tiempo de ejecución, ya que pertenecen al namespace tools.
tools:layout Este atributo declara el diseño que se quiere que genere
la vista previa de diseño dentro del fragmento, pero estos atributos solo funcionan para la vista previa en el editor de diseño y no se aplican en tiempo de ejecución.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SuperIRC"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintMarginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintMarginTop="16dp"/>
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintMarginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintMarginTop="16dp"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

